# multiple array of lat lang for google data matrix not working but working for only 1 item in array?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

i am using this [google services js api](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-js) and I am not sure why this code works for individual lat/lang?

```
 const { data } = await GoogleClient.distancematrix({
              params: {
                origins: [[userLocation.latitude, userLocation.longitude]],
                destinations: [
                  [
                    node.merchant.geometry.coordinates[0],
                    node.merchant.geometry.coordinates[1],
                  ] as LatLng,
                ],
                key: GOOGLE_API_KEY,
                units: UnitSystem.imperial,
              },
            });
```

what i wanted to do is pass multiple origins and destinations in 1 call:

```
  const destinations = data.nearbyCampaigns.edges.map(
          ({ node }) =>
            [node.merchant.geometry.coordinates[0], node.merchant.geometry.coordinates[1]] as LatLng
        );
        //e.g.: destinations =  [[8.532997603846151,124.34326170144848],[8.542997603846151,124.34326170144848],[8.552997603846151,124.34326170144848]]
        const origins = destinations.map(
          (_) => [userLocation.latitude, userLocation.longitude] as LatLng
        );
        //e.g.: origins = [[8.55381,124.523956],[8.54981,124.523956],[8.55981,124.523956]]
        const { data: data1 } = await GoogleClient.distancematrix({
          params: {
            origins: [...origins],
            destinations: [...destinations],
            key: GOOGLE_API_KEY,
            units: UnitSystem.imperial,
          },
        });
```

but doing that i will get this error:

```
{"destination_addresses":["","",""],"origin_addresses":["","",""],"rows":[{"elements":[{"status":"NOT_FOUND"},{"status":"NOT_FOUND"},{"status":"NOT_FOUND"}]},{"elements":[{"status":"NOT_FOUND"},{"status":"NOT_FOUND"},{"status":"NOT_FOUND"}]},{"elements":[{"status":"NOT_FOUND"},{"status":"NOT_FOUND"},{"status":"NOT_FOUND"}]}],"status":"OK"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy way on how to pass multiple origin and destination using [Node.js Client for Google Maps Services](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-js). I base my code on how the github document shows how the Google Maps API should be called. I used your origin and destinations coordinates and put them in a json file.

Main.js

```
let origin = require("./origin.json")
let dest = require("./destination.json")

let originArray = origin.geometry;
let destArray = dest.geometry;

const {
    Client
} = require("@googlemaps/google-maps-services-js");
const client = new Client({});


client
    .distancematrix({
        params: {
            origins: originArray,
            destinations: destArray,
            key: "YOUR_API_KEY",
        }
    })
    .then((r) => {
        console.log(r.data);
    })
    .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e.response.data.error_message);
    });
```

origin.json

```
{"geometry":[
  {"lat":8.55381, "lng":124.523956},
  {"lat":88.54981, "lng":124.523956},
  {"lat":8.55981, "lng":124.523956}
]}
```

destination.json

```
{"geometry":[
  {"lat":8.532997603846151, "lng":124.34326170144848},
  {"lat":8.542997603846151, "lng":124.34326170144848},
  {"lat":8.552997603846151, "lng":124.34326170144848}
]}
``
```